# Grounding question: Honda eu7000is generator connected through PG&E backup power transfer meter

Tags: grounding, generator, grounding-and-bonding, transfer-switch

Earlier this year PG&E installed a free backup power transfer meter at our California property ([info sheet here](https://www.pge.com/assets/pge/docs/outages-and-safety/outage-preparedness-and-support/bptm-fact-sheet.pdf)). Using the cable supplied with the meter, it connects our Honda eu7000is inverter generator ([manual](https://cdn.powerequipment.honda.com/pe/pdf/manuals/00x31z376011.pdf)) to power the whole house.

We have noticed some odd behavior on the gas furnace (2009 vintage) and TV (2021 vintage). In the past, using a smaller eu2000is generator, this furnace refused to fire up until I strapped ground to neutral. While the furnace seems to work with the new transfer switch and generator, it did shut off unexpectedly one time while on generator power. Similarly, the television shut off unexpectedly one time while on generator power.

The question is, should we bond the generator ground screw to the grounding rod at the power meter? This would be an easy task. According to the generator manual, "This generator has a system ground that connects generator frame components to ground terminals in the AC output receptacles. The system ground is not connected to the AC neutral wire."